# HttpAsyncPost setting headers

Tags: java, asynchronous, httpclient

I am currenty using Apache's HttpComponents including the HttpAsyncClient beta, but I was wondering. How do I set the headers for a HttpAsyncPost?

I currently have:

```
HttpAsyncPost asyncRequest = new HttpAsyncPost(channel, "id=15846");
```

But how do I set the headers for this request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `HttpAsyncMethods#create` method in order to create an `HttpAsyncRequestProducer` from an arbitrary `HttpUriRequest` instance, if you do not mind upgrading to the latest snapshot.

Alternatively, you can override `HttpAsyncPost#createRequest()` method and add custom headers to the `HttpEntityEnclosingRequest` instance returned by the super class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My first solution using cast to `BasicAsyncRequestProducer`. I can't rely on method `generateRequest()` which is basically getter but it would change in the future as name of the method suggests. So I sticked to [@oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg) answer.

```
BasicAsyncRequestProducer request = (BasicAsyncRequestProducer) HttpAsyncMethods.createPost("http://some/uri", "some payload", ContentType.DEFAULT_TEXT);
request.generateRequest().setHeader("header name", "header value");
```

Using my own `createPost` method based on [@oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg) answer:

```
createPost("http://some/uri", "some payload", ContentType.DEFAULT_TEXT, new BasicHeader("header name", "header value")); 

static class RequestProducerImpl extends BasicAsyncRequestProducer {

    protected RequestProducerImpl(
        final HttpHost target,
        final HttpEntityEnclosingRequest request,
        final HttpAsyncContentProducer producer) {
        super(target, request, producer);
    }
}

public static HttpAsyncRequestProducer createPost(
    final String requestURI,
    final String content,
    final ContentType contentType, Header... headers) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(requestURI);
    final NStringEntity entity = new NStringEntity(content, contentType);
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    httppost.setHeaders(headers);
    final HttpHost target = URIUtils.extractHost(URI.create(requestURI));
    return new RequestProducerImpl(target, httppost, entity);
}
```